# Forms in Symfony2 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, odm

I have this class for member :

```
class Member {
/**
 * @ODM\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ODM\String
 */
protected $fName;

/**
 * @ODM\String
 */
protected $lName;

/**
 * @ODM\String
 */
protected $email;


/**
 * @ODM\String
 */
protected $password;

//getters & setters

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getFName().$this->getLName();
}
```

And this FormType for its form :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MemberType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fName', 'text')
            ->add('lName', 'text')
            ->add('password', 'password')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('sigIn', 'submit');
        $builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\MainBundle\Document\Member',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'member';
    }
}
```

and in a controller i use this to render the form :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new MemberType(), 'member');

    return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Default:index2.html.twig',
        array('register'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

It looks like to work,but when I check it I see this error in browser :

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
Prexter\MainBundle\Document\Member, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error
by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that
transforms a(n) string to an instance of Prexter\MainBundle\Document\Member.
```

I have set data_class to null,but nothing changed!please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an instance of `Member` as the second argument for `Controller#createForm()`, instead of the string "member". Eg:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MemberType(), new Member());
```